# Object.keys returns an object in node 4.2.2. I need an Array

Tags: node.js

In the node repl Object.keys seems to work just fine, returning an Array of the keys.

```
> Object.keys({id: 1})
[ 'id' ]
```

But Array functions like *includes* don't work.

```
> Object.keys({id: 1}).includes('id')
TypeError: Object.keys(...).includes is not a function
    at repl:1:22
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:248:27)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:412:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:549:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:826:14)
```

This led me to check the type and surprise surpise! It's an Object.

```
> typeof(Object.keys({id: 1}))
'object'
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? How can I get an Array from Object.keys?

Comment: The `Array.includes` method may not be available in node `4.2.2`, it's from a recent standard. Try `indexOf`

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks!